# Swift 3 : Issue with cursor of textView when touched by the user

Tags: ios, swift

I've been struggling with a rather stupid issue for a few days now and I have not been able to find a solution.

I have a view controller with the following hierarchy: [xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf0vn.png)

The user will have the possibility to add pictures below the textView (I haven't implemented this feature yet).
I set the "scrolling enabled" property of my textView to false so that its height automatically increases or decreases depending on the content typed by the user, which is working as expected.
I use the notification center in order to change the scrollView's contentInsets when the keyboard is shown like so:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

    var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
    contentInsets.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height + 3*self.postContentTextView.font!.lineHeight
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
}
```

with the following observers in viewDidLoad:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

I also set the scroll view content size in the viewDidLayoutSubviews function:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.postContentTextView.frame.size
}
```

Everything seemed to work fine until I realize that when the text is "too long" (or maybe it is something else), I am not able to select the last lines of the textView when I touch them. Actually, when I touch the screen the cursor is supposed to appear on the line I have just touched. This works normally for three quarters of the textView but it looks like the textView does not detect my finger for the last lines (the bigger the height is, the worse this issue is).
At the beginning, I thought I had a problem with my screen but I tested it on the iOS Simulator and the same problem occurred.
I have to admit that I am completely clueless about it. Does any of you have an idea of what the problem could be ?

Comment: May be you have a transparent view added accidentally. any possibilities for that?

Comment: Have you checked its constraints? The textView might be outside the bounds of its superviews. Set `clipsToBounds` to superview & test it. If it is out of the superview bounds, it will not detect touch

Comment: That's it Bali! My textView becomes bigger than my content view when the text is too long. How come I did not think of that ? Thank you very much! Problem solved.

Comment: I will add it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked its constraints? The `UITextView` might be outside the `bounds` of its superviews. Set `clipsToBounds` to superview & test it. If it is out of the superview `bounds`, it will not detect touch